# Loop over two data objects in JavaScript and combine to produce desired result

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dictionary

I have an array and a dictionary below:

```
this.rank  = {
  1: "Ace",
  2: "Two",
  3: "Three",
  4: "Four",
  5: "Five",
  6: "Six",
  7: "Seven",
  8: "Eight",
  9: "Nine",
  10: "Ten",
  11: "Jack",
  12: "Queen",
  13: "King"
};
  this.suit = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
```

How can I loop over both of these to give a deck of cards?

I currently have this but am confused as to how to add the suits in?

```
this.cards = []

  for (var key in this.rank) {
    if (this.rank.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      this.cards.push(key)
    }
```

Alternatively, is there a better/simpler way entirely?

Comment: Any reason you're not using an array for your ranks?

Comment: How do you want the data formatted and arranged when the code is done with it?

Comment: it is important that they have a value for a game where higher and lower are considered..

Comment: i want an array called like this `this.cards = ['2H', '7S', 'KingD']` etc

Comment: [`var rank = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"],
    suit = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S'];

for (var i = 0, suitLen = suit.length; i < suitLen; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, len = rank.length; j < len; j++) {
        console.log(rank[j] + suit[i]);
    }
}`](https://jsfiddle.net/swp1rk3d/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through `this.suits` or hard-code the 4 indexes.

```js
this.rank = {
  1: "Ace",
  2: "Two",
  3: "Three",
  4: "Four",
  5: "Five",
  6: "Six",
  7: "Seven",
  8: "Eight",
  9: "Nine",
  10: "Ten",
  11: "Jack",
  12: "Queen",
  13: "King"
};

this.suit = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']

this.cards = []

for (var key in this.rank) {
  if (this.rank.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // you could loop through this.suit but for only 4 iterations it's probably faster just to hard code
    this.cards.push(this.rank[key] + this.suit[0]);
    this.cards.push(this.rank[key] + this.suit[1]);
    this.cards.push(this.rank[key] + this.suit[2]);
    this.cards.push(this.rank[key] + this.suit[3]);
  }
}

console.log(this.cards);
```

Comment: cheers, this looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that utlizes *map*. You didn't specify the data structure you want to end up with, but it's easily modified from here.

```
cards.map(function(currVal){
  suit.map(function(secVal){
    console.log(currVal + ' ' + secVal);
  })
})
```